# AWS Lambda multiple triggers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, boto3

I have three s3 buckets that are invoking a lambda function whenever there is a change in the content of specific objects inside the buckets.

Does anyone know if it is possible, using boto3, to retrieve those objects that have triggered the function?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I would like to get the objects that have triggered the lambda function from the response contents. I have tried to get it from the response of the get_function method of the lambda client but to no avail:

```
 import boto3
 lam = boto3.client('lambda')
 response = lam.get_function(FunctionName='mylambdafunction')
```

Comment: inside lambda you can access those objects as change detection.

Comment: Yes, you can retrieve S3 objects using boto3. See the boto3 docs. Note: you aren't being invoked when there is a change in content so much as being invoked when a new object is uploaded or an existing object is replaced or a new version is written (if you enabled versioning). You can't update S3 objects.

Comment: Add  IAM policy and inside Cloudwatch you can check all logs

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible? What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to retrieve the object that triggered the AWS Lambda function invocation:

```py
import urllib
import boto3

# Connect to S3
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# This handler is executed every time the Lambda function is triggered
def lambda_handler(event, context):

  # Get the bucket and object key from the Event
  bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
  key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
  localFilename = '/tmp/foo.txt'

  # Download the file from S3 to the local filesystem
  s3_client.download_file(bucket, key, localFilename)

  # Do other stuff here
```

Basically, it extracts the Bucket and Key (filename) from the `event` data that is passed to the function, then calls `download_file()`.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply.  This works when I run the lambda function.  Basically my lambda function is also running an AWS Glue Job.  Is it possible to call the bucket that triggered the lambda function inside the Glue Job?  Reason being is that I only want to do a Glue Job on the data set that was changed.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar enough with AWS Glue to answer that. Perhaps you should create a new question specifically asking about this?